# Port conflict in Pi-Hole Docker installation with systemd-resolve process

Tags: networking, dns, docker, systemd-resolved

I am trying to install Pi-Hole alongside Nextcloud on my Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 20.04. NextCloud is installed normally on the top of Ubuntu, whereas I am trying to install Pi-Hole in a container to avoid any conflicts with the webserver.

I am following this guide: https://rsw.io/how-to-install-pi-hole-in-a-docker-container-on-a-raspberry-pi/

This is the error I am getting

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for pihole/pihole:latest
Creating pihole ...
Creating pihole ... error

ERROR: for pihole  Cannot start service pihole: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pihole (56f233c57287a526a4e6adc3038d9359cda06ba8b51c0157146c42171cc47106): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for pihole  Cannot start service pihole: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pihole (56f233c57287a526a4e6adc3038d9359cda06ba8b51c0157146c42171cc47106): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Port 53 is already in use by systemd-resolve:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/pi-hole# sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P -n +c 10
COMMAND       PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-re  41186 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4 167233      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
```

I have tried (stupidly) to stop the process system-re but this has broken all the DNS.

What does the process systemd-resolve do and what can I do to avoid the conflict with port 53, please?

Comment: Just a wild guess but this could be caused by the fact that you are running Ubuntu and not Raspberry Pi OS (Raspbian). I guess that most users of the docker-image uses the "default" OS and if you use Ubuntu you will have to modify the docker compose-file to fit your environment and needs.

Comment: Solved with this: https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/setup-on-pi-in-docker-bind-error/19137/7

Answer (score 1):

Port 53 is being used by systemd.resolved. This article explains how to fix

http://web.archive.org/web/20220612212822/https://www.bklynit.net/ubuntu-20-04-lts-docker-pihole/

Per this article

Step 5: Stop systemd-resolve from listening on port 53 -

Edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` - uncomment the line with `DNSStubListener` and change yes to no.

Restart systemd-resolved with
`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`

Fix local dns resolution by removing the symlink to the systemd stub-resolv.conf and replace it with a link to a full resolv.conf

`sudo rm /etc/resolve.conf`

`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Can you give a little more detail in your answer? 'Link' answers can be problematic, see here under 'Provide context for links': https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer